# Bash need refresh for accessing new file?

Tags: bash, shell

I ran the `maven test` and it's **ended** in a terminal. In another terminal, I `ls target/surefire-reports` and just find no report here. So I `cd ..` and enter the directory second times, my file is here! So, Bash need refresh for accessing new file? But when I doing something like `head file0 > file1` in a terminal, I can find my file instantly with `ls` in another terminal.

My instruction here:

In the first terminal:

```
[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target/surefire-reports]
$mvn test

.....

[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target/surefire-reports]
$

(ended)
```

In the second terminal:

```
[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target/surefire-reports]
$ls

[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target/surefire-reports]
$ll -al
total 0

[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target/surefire-reports]
$cd ..

[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target]
$cd surefire-reports/

[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target/surefire-reports]
$ls
mycode.txt  TEST-mycode.xml

[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target/surefire-reports]
$
```

Comment: I doesn't need to be refreshed, my guess is that the report file was not ready yet.

Comment: @jeanrjc But `mvn test` is ended... I try this for many times. If it is not ready , why I always see it ready after the `re-entering`? I mean, it is possible the file is not ready yet when I re-enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the current directory is being deleted and re-created.  This would explain why you can't see anything until you enter the same directory again--the director you're in is actually gone, and a new one by the same name has been created.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the directory `surefire-report` you were in has been removed and re-created, so when you run "ls" you try to get the listing of the current directory, which no longer exists. Try having the parent directory as current directory and run `ls` like this:

```
[me@host1 /home/me/interest/target]
$ ls surefire-reports
```

I think this will give the correct listing